# Kubernetes: Kafka pod shutdown after server stops

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm

I am running a Kafka pod in Kubernetes with Rancher. I am using the confluent image and it is connecting properly to zookeeper. I am using the stable helm chart with the Kafka confluent image 5.3.1. I also added SSL encryption into Helm using this [page](https://medium.com/weareservian/encryption-authentication-and-external-access-for-confluent-kafka-on-kubernetes-69c723a612fc)
It is starting properly then it shutdown abruptly and pod restart. I am getting this error on the log.

> [2019-11-15 19:41:49,943] INFO Terminating process due to signal SIGTERM (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
>   [2019-11-15 19:41:49,945] INFO Shutting down SupportedServerStartable (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable)

What is the SIGTERM error in Kafka pods? How to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: SIGTERM is not an error. The pod is being stopped either externally or by some other process.

Comment: well, that's kafka sending the SEGTERM for sure (I believe this is the guy `org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler`), but why is that is unclear. I would open an issue on github with them.

Comment: I was able to solve it by removing the livenessProbe. Look into the Kubernetes or Rancher logs and see what is failing.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Hamzatli, it is about liveness and readiness. K8s thinks that your pod is hitting a timeout issue and sends the SIGTERM to the pod for it to shutdown.

In your Helm Chart's values.yaml, there should be an option about liveness and/or readiness. Increase the initialDelaySeconds to a higher time, which you think is enough time for the Kafka to be brought up, so that k8s doesn't send the shutdown signal too quickly during initial startup.

```
livenessProbe:
  enabled: true
  initialDelaySeconds: 60   # 60 seconds delay for the pod to start liveness probe
  timeoutSeconds: 5
readinessProbe:
  enabled: true
  initialDelaySeconds: 60   # 60 seconds delay for pod to start readiness probe
  timeoutSeconds: 5
```

You can read more about this [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes).

Answer (score 0):

This is liveness and readiness problem. When kafka attempt to read topic snapshots liveness ping to kafka and it can't respond. So k8 shutdown kafka.
Remove liveness and readiness